# How to implement JSF 2.3 on Google App Engine Project

Tags: google-app-engine, primefaces, jsf-2.3

I'm trying to create a Web Application on Google App Engine (GAE).
I want to use Primefaces 7.0 and, obviously, JSF 2.3, but I can't understand which dependencies need to add to *pom.xml* (yes, is a maven project) to get a working project.

Answer (score 0):

The MyFaces JSF implementation has GAE support as you can read here
https://myfaces.apache.org/core20/googleappenginesupport.html
and here
http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces2-googleappengine-eclipse-tutorial.html

I'm however not sure if its still usable like this. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks, I had already read this post and not, I would like at least JSF 2.2: we are in 2020, not in 2012.

Comment: Try it with 2.3, it should work ;)
We didn't changed the integration code but we also didn't test it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-22/configuring-jsf-22-to-run-on-the-google-app-engine-using-eclipse) you can find a complete guide on how to configure JSF 2.2 to run on App Engine. In this tutorial they download and add the libraries manually.

Further there are some [compatibility issues](https://sites.google.com/a/wildstartech.com/adventures-in-java/google-app-engine-for-java/using-javaserver-faces-on-the-google-app-engine/compatibility-issues) that may be taken into consideration.